# Why isn't my session variable being set?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've recently encountered a problem while programming a log-in script. Take a look at my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($submit)){
    require 'db/connect.php';
    $sql = "SELECT id from users WHERE password='$password' AND email='$email'";
    $entered_user = mysql_query($sql);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($entered_user);

    $errors = array();

    if( $num_rows != 1 )
    {
        $errors[] = '-Account does not exist ';
    }
    elseif( $num_rows == 1 )
    {
        session_start();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($entered_user)){
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $password;
            header('Location: profile.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
}   
?>
```

After the user has submitted their password and email, I attempt to store the following in session variables: id, username, password and email.
However for some reason the username is not being stored and outputted on profile.php, where they are redirected. Here is my profile.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Profile</title>
  <link href='css/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
  <?php require 'include/header.php'; ?>

  <?= 'NJM ID # ==>'.$_SESSION['id'].'<br />'.'Username ==>'.$_SESSION['user'].'<br/>'.'Password ==>'.$_SESSION['pass'] ?>

  <?php require 'include/footer.php'; ?>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone knows how to fix this issue please help. I have only learned HTML, CSS, JS and PHP about 2 months ago so I AM a beginner :)

Comment: Because you only select  id in your query!!!

Comment: `SELECT id FROM` only selects the `id` make this `SELECT id, username FROM`

Comment: I have tried selecting username too by adding 'AND username', still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you so much. Also - Is there a way to close a question after receiving an appropriate response on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yes, choose the answer below as the correct/accepted answer

Comment: I might as well say what everyone else is thinking: `mysql_query` is officially deprecated. You should switch to `mysqli` or even step over to PDO.

Comment: My web host does not support mysqli_* :(

Comment: You should: 1. Start your session `session_start()` at the top of your script and 2. Stop using `mysql_*` functions as these are deprecated and unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a few remarks on your code which will probably fix all your issues.

1. Sessions should be started before any of the other code is executed. This will prevent strange problems from arising.
2. Check if the session isn't already set.

Recommended way for versions of PHP >= 5.4.0

```
if ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE ) {
    session_start();
}
```

For versions of PHP < 5.4.0

```
if (session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```

3. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` to do your queries. `mysql_*` is deprecated and fairly unsafe.
4. Your query isn't fetchin the username

Change:

```
$sql = "SELECT id
from users
WHERE password='$password'
AND email='$email'";
```

to:

```
$sql = "SELECT
id AS id,
username AS username
FROM users
WHERE password='".$password."'
AND email='".$email."'";
```

Comment: here `id AS id, username as username` is necessary. only `id, username` is pretty enough.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$sql = "SELECT id from users WHERE password='$password' AND email='$email'";
```

to this

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username from users WHERE password='$password' AND email='$email'";
```

or this

```
$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE password='$password' AND email='$email'";
```